# Recording the script in Jmeter for Applications having Google map

Tags: jmeter

I'm new to jmeter.I'm testing the webapp running in local network which is having google map in it.I want to record using the recording controller.

I have set the proxy in jmeter by

**-H webproxyServer -P 80 -u username -a password -N localhost**

and used the jmeter proxy server in Browser. I tried to record the script.But Google map is not loading in the application.Can anyone help in this?

Answer (score 0):

You're misusing `-H` command line argument. It's required when your host doesn't have Internet  connection and JMeter cannot access the website under test only via proxy.

There are 2 options available on how to record network traffic into JMeter .jmx file:

1. [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP%28S%29_Test_Script_Recorder) + Recording Controller. See [JMeter Proxy Step by Step](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf) guide for the detailed walkthrough.
2. [Google Chrome JMeter Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-load-testi/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi?hl=en) which allows JMeter scripts recording right from browser without needing to worry about proxies, SSL certificates, headers, etc.